# Extract specific key and value in Logstash

Tags: mysql, json, logstash

Im using Logastash to collecting data from mysql. Json result looks :

```
 "_source" : {
            "username" : "room_test@localhost",
            "timestamp" : 1481785195811703,
            "peer" : "user@localhost/1596084304715518942270426",
            "bare_peer" : "user@localhost",
            "xml" : "<message to='room_test1481784717020@localhost' type='groupchat' from='user@localhost'><body>msg</body><jid>456-345</jid></message>",
            "txt" : "msg",
            "id" : 6452,
            "kind" : "groupchat",
            "nick" : "user",
            "created_at" : "2016-12-15T06:59:55.000Z",
            "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2017-02-25T12:17:52.043Z"
          }
```

I need extract value from "xml" key as separate value. Like this "jid": 456-345

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grok can handle this.

```
grok {
  match => {
    "xml" => "<jid>(?<jid>[-0-9]{4,9})</jid>"
  }
}
```

This will create a `jid` field equal to the value you supplied. The value in the JID tag in the XML can be between 4 and 9 characters long. Adjust as you need to.